# Autoplay videos on scroll as window focuses

Tags: javascript, html, web

A video blog where the videos are 800x600 pixels (take most of browser screen).
I am using html  tag with attributes 'loop' and 'autoplay'

With more then 10 videos so far, the browser plays all of them a stalls!

I need a piece of code to play one video at a time as the user scrolls to the video in focus and pause the video as soon as out of scroll focus.

Comment: Using the verge.js lightweight library, you could detect your video elements in the viewport using one of the library's `$.inViewport()` methods then play them if the method returns `true`
http://verge.airve.com/

Answer (score 1):

If the videos are evenly spaced at 600px high and lets assume the margins on the videos are at least 50px, that means each video has a functional height of 700px. So you want to play the video that is closest to the top of your screen.

`const qVideos = document.querySelectorAll('video');`

^ This assumes you are using the video element to play videos and is collecting them.

`const calcVideoNumber = scrollPositionY => Math.floor( scrollPositionY / 700 );`

^This function takes in your scroll position and returns the number of 700px (this should be your video section height) high sections you are down the page.

`const stopPlaying = videos => Array.from(videos).forEach( video => video.pause() );`

^ Stops playing all of the passed videos

`window.onscroll = event => {
    stopPlaying(qVideos);
    qVideos[calcVideoNumber(event.scrollY)].play()
}`